# Searching from a table generated using LIKE MySQL

Tags: mysql

I like to search from a table in MySQL using a result from another query. For example I generated a result like this

```
ID | fname | lname 

1  | Joe   | Hal

2  | Joel  | summers

16 | Shejoe| Cruz
```

using this query:

```
Select * from users_tbl where fname like %joe%
```

Now I want to filter that generated result using another like statement. I tried this query

```
Select * from users_tbl where lname like %c% in (Select * from users_tbl where fname like %joe%)
```

But I always get an error saying

> You have an error in syntax near ' %c% in (Select * from users_tbl where fname like %joe%)

Comment: Why can't you just add another condition with `AND`?

Comment: Error is because inside in caluse you should specify one column

Comment: Aside from the above error, these statements won't work because `LIKE` needs a quoted string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions are

```
        Select * from users_tbl where lname like '%c%' and  fname like '%joe%'
```

Comment: I just realized how idiot I am. Thank you. You just saved my life :)

Comment: @halfer you are right I missed but I updated my answer . Thanks for correcting .